# How to use image in R shiny with htmlTemplate

Tags: html, r, shiny

I have a `template.html` file and am loading it like this:

[image]

I am trying to include an image using the HTML `img` tag. The relative path is correct. I have tried putting the image in the same directory as `template.html` but it is not finding it. How can I include an image in the `template.html` file?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

shiny will make available any resources in a folder named *www/*, in the same location as your `app.R` or `ui.R`/`server.R` files.

Create a folder named *www/* and put the *images* folder in there and that should resolve it.